# How to Save the values of check boxes to session storage and retrieve them on the next page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to save the data of the first check boxes to session Storage and I would like to retrieve the data and set them to the second page on load from the session storage.

**1st HTML**

```html
<body>
  <label for="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="1" checked="checked" value="1" >1
</label>
  <label for="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="2" value="2" >2
</label>
  <label for="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="3" value="3" >3
</label>
  <label for="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="4" value="4" >4
</label>
  <button onclick="saveSession()">save</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function saveSession() {
      // I want to save the value of the radio button to sessionStorage here
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

In my second HTML I would like to retrieve this data and set the value of the radio buttons to the same.

**2nd HTML**

```html
<body onload="type()">
  <label for="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="1" checked="checked" value="1" >1
</label>
  <label for="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="2" value="2" >2
</label>
  <label for="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="3" value="3" >3
</label>
  <label for="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="num" id="4" value="4" >4
</label>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function type() {
      //I want to get the data with sessionStorage.getItem()
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this step by step.

To get a value from a checkbox you can do the following:

```
const value = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').value
```

To save it on the storage you do the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('num-value', value)
```

Wrapping it up for the 1st page:

```
function saveSession() {
  const value = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').value
  localStorage.setItem('num-value', value)
}
```

And then in the 2nd page, we get it from the storage

```
function type() {
  const value = localStorage.getItem('num-value')
  console.log('value', value) // console it
}
```

*Edit:

If you want for multiple values you have to do the following

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))

const checkValues = elements.map(input => input.checked)
```

And then as it's an array of values, you must save it as a JSON string

```
localStorage.setItem('num-value', JSON.stringify(checkValues))
```

Now, in the 2nd page, in order to get them values you must to the same transformation, but now from JSON to string.

```
const checkValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('num-value'))
```

And then, finally you update the 2nd page checkboxes with the correct values:

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach((input, index) => input.checked = checkValues[index]) // you get the value based on the index
```

Note that I'm using some functions from document. 
I recommend you take a deeper look into [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: And how do I use that value in the second page to check the boxes according?

Comment: Hmm, you can try do the following:
`document.querySelector(\`input[value="${ value  }"]\`).checked = true;`, the value being the one that you got from localStorage

Comment: this only checks 1 of the options that I've selected not all of them.

Comment: yeah surely, querySelector only works for one element, to help you I'll create an edit to that question

Comment: Thanks it works better if you add `index+1` in the last line.